# Confusion Matrix & Bayes

Tags: bayesian, confusion-matrix

With knowing the probability of True Negative P(TN), the probability of Predict Negative P(TN+FN), and the probability of True Negative Given Predict Negative P(TN|TN+FN), are we able to calculate the probability of True Positive Given Predict Positive P(TP|TP+FP)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on *why* you're unable to calculate the probabilities you describe. If you don't have any data in the first place, you obviously cannot compute any probabilities at all. If you are given only the number of TP and FP, you cannot calculate P(TN), P(TN+FN), nor P(TN|TN+FN), but calculating P(TP|TP+FP) is trivial. If you have the full confusion matrix, you can compute any of the probabilities you want, since you know the number of TP, FP, TN, and FN.